# Question about @BindingMethod in this code

Tags: android-databinding

Slide title resolving setter I read this slide , but i don't understand BindingMethod, we must write this method any where? or it just  explain how stuff work.

```
    I know for exemple we must write write BindingAdapter for some attribue like bellow
```

```
    <TextView android : text = "@{myVariable}"/>
    textView.setText(myVariable);


    <ImageView android:src="@{user.image}"/>


     imageView.setImageDrawable(user.image); 

     @BindingMethod( 
            type = android.widget.ImageView.class, 
            attribute = "android:src",
            method = "setImageDrawable")
```

Comment: I think method 1 is equivalente method 2, so we have choise to write in our java method 1 or method2
<ImageView android:src="@{user.image}"/>
// method 1
 imageView.setImageDrawable(user.image); 
 // method 2
 @BindingMethod( 
       type = android.widget.ImageView.class, 
       attribute = "android:src",
        method = "setImageDrawable")

Answer (score 0):

```
I think method 1 is equivalente method 2, so we have choise to write in our java method 1 or method2 <ImageView android:src="@{user.image}"/> // method 1 imageView.setImageDrawable(user.image); // method 2 @BindingMethod( type = android.widget.ImageView.class, attribute = "android:src", method = "setImageDrawable")
```

But now i want to know when we use @BindingMethod and when we use @BindingAdapter.